# Error in get last ID from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I want to make a stored procedure, and then get the `ID` that I've just created (identity)

This is what I did :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Insert_Hai_Pi]
@id INT OUT,
@email VARCHAR(350) = NULL,
@datetimeNow datetime,
@score INT  = 0
AS 

INSERT INTO TBL_HAI_PI (USER_EMAIL,DATETIME_GAME,CORRECT_ANSWERS) VALUES (@email, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@score) 

SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
return @id
```

and then :

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_Insert_Hai_Pi", conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;

conn.Open();
int tempId = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
return tempId;
```

Tt tells me :

> *Procedure or function 'SP_Insert_Hai_Pi' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied.*

What's wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried to add an integer id parameter: `int id;    
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is output you have to define it:

```
 ..... 
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 SqlParameter outputIdParam = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
   { 
      Direction = ParameterDirection.Output 
   };

   command.Parameters.Add(outputIdParam);
   command.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
 .....
```